# Explain me the following C program's output

Tags: c

Please explain me the following example. The problem is simple but the results are abrupt.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int flag = 0;
  char passwd[10];
  strcpy(passwd, argv[1]);
  if(0 == strcmp("LinuxGeek", passwd))
    {
      flag = 1;
    }

  if(flag)
    {
      printf("\n Password cracked \n");
    }
  else
    {
      printf("\n Incorrect passwd \n");

    }
  return 0;
}
```

The value of flag is changing to garbage value after the line

```
strcpy(passwd, argv[1]);
```

However, if I define the variable flag like,

```
int flag = 0
```

after the line

```
strcpy(passwd, argv[1]);
```

I get the desired result. Please explain it to me in brief.

Comment: In brief: undefined behavior.

Comment: More problems than that, what happens if the length of argv[1] > 10 chars...

Comment: Character movement is performed differently in different implementations. Thus, overlapping moves may yield surprises.

Comment: strncpy() is more robust than strcpy() at avoiding undesired buffer overrun corruption. What happens to your stack frame when user enters a value of argv[1] exceeding 9 characters?

Comment: seems like a hacker 101 example

Comment: apart from the string manipulation discussions the Flag value is not garbage , i just tested it and it gives 0

Comment: Ugh, Yoda comparisons. They still teach that? And do we help with password crackers here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I printed the address of `flag` and `passwd` I got `0x7fff3315c91c` and `0x7fff3315c910` respectively.
So I concluded that the value of `passwd` is overwriting the value of flag if the size of the argv[1] is greater than 12(as the difference between the addresses of `flag` and `passwd` 12).

`passwd` address model `(0x7fff3315c910):` `| 10  | 11 | 12 | ........... | 1A | 1B |`

`flag` address model `(0x7fff3315c91c):` `| 1C | ........`

From above we can see that the address of `flag` is over written by the value of `passwd`

Comment: Yes Sutirtha, I agree with you. I did the same and understood how the memory is getting overwritten. I used malloc() for passwd  and my code  worked. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is that the behavior of your program is undefined when the length of `argv[1]` is greater than nine, because then you overflow the buffer `passwd`.

The long answer is that apparently, your compiler orders the variables on the stack in the order listed, so moving `flag` after `passwd` puts four extra zero bytes after the buffer and `strcmp` recognizes one of these as a NUL terminator on `passwd`.

The solution to the problem is to skip the useless copying:

```
char *passwd = argv[1];
```

Or remove the `passwd` variable altogether and do the following comparison:

```
strcmp("LinuxGeek", argv[1])
```

Comment: Not to forget that there's no checking to see whether `argc` is greater than 1 at all.

Answer (score 1):

You don't perform any check (length, null byte) on the strings you are manipulating, especially `argv`. For example the input password might not fit in your `passwd` variable.